# cgi file utilizing perl to find uptime

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a cgi file using perl where I want to display localtime and uptime. I cannot seem to get uptime to work correctly

I am trying to set variable $utime = uptime but this does not work currently. I tried using /proc/uptime as well and that did not work. Below is what I have tried so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#Script Name: sysInfo.cgi

use CGI ":standard";

$loctime = localtime;
$utime = uptime;

print header,
        start_html("Localtime and Uptime"),
        h1("$loctime"),
        h1("$utime"),
        end_html;
```

I am sure I am missing something simple but I just keep getting uptime as a string when executing in my browser.

Comment: please show examples of what you expect to store in `$loctime` and `$utime`

Comment: Where is `uptime` defined in your code?

Comment: You *really* need to `use strict;` (and `use warnings;` instead of `-w` on the command line... Are you learning from a seriously outdated source?)

Comment: Plus of course, there's [this warning about CGI.pm html generation functions](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used)..

Comment: loctime will display localtime (i.e. Thu Apr 18 22:29:07 2019) and utime will display uptime (i.e. 22:33:57 up 454 days, 18:12,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant lines of the code are:

```
$loctime = localtime;
$utime = uptime;
```

These behave somewhat differently.

The first calls the Perl function "localtime" and assigns its result to the variable. Because it is called in scalar context, the function returns a human readable string.

The second line should produce a warning of some sort unless you have defined `uptime` somewhere in your program. Perhaps:

> Unquoted string "uptime" may clash with future reserved word

This explains why `$utime` ends up contains the word "uptime".

It seems you want to call the unix command `uptime` and assign its output to the variable. For this, one would normally use some variant of `qx//` (aka backticks):

```
$utime = `/usr/bin/uptime`;

$utime = qx( /usr/bin/uptime );
```

See [`perldoc -f qx`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html) for details.

Comment: $utime = qx( /usr/bin/uptime ); works perfectly. From what I was reading online I though "uptime" was a perl function, but as you pointed out it is a unix command. That is what was throwing me off. Thank you